# go build from different repositories with different proxy settings

Tags: go, build, proxy

I use go-modules to build  my go-project. The project uses deps from github.com and git.companyname.com. 
But github.com requires proxy-settings. After calling "go build" command it  downloads deps from local repository and stops at github.com repositores as needs proxy. That is why I stil download manually all dependencies. Is there a way to configure go compiler to use different proxy setting for direrent git repositories?

Comment: This might help `go help module-private`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
$ git config --global url."<proxy-url>".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Comment: Can it get all dependencies from github.com(requires proxy) and git.somecompany.com(no proxy) after running "go build"?thanks

Comment: The above commad means, whenever go module try to fetch from `https://github.com/`, it will be forwarded to the given `<proxy-url>`. So, it will not forward the calls for other URLs.